# Using Arcpy to copy features in a loop to a differing workspace

Tags: arcpy, copy

I've tried to create a script to loop through a folder and then clip the features. This works. My problem is that my new files are created in the same workspace (in my case Data) but I would like to save them in a different workspace (a geodatabase).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True

env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Victor\Carto\Data"

clip = r"C:\Users\Victor\Carto\XXX.shp"

list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print list

for l_list in list:
 filename = os.path.splitext(l_list)[0]
 clip_filename = filename + "_GL"
 arcpy.Clip_analysis(l_list, clip, clip_filename, 0)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the default workspace, or specifying a target geodatabase in the output path?  Right now the software is just doing what you've asked it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path to your geodatabase in the clip tool.

For example, if you have a geodatabase called `my_gdb` and it's located in  `c://data`

```
gdb = r'c:/data/my_gdb'
for l_list in list:
  clip_filename = '{0}_GL'.format(os.path.splitext(l_list)[0])
  arcpy.Clip_analysis(l_list, clip, os.path.join(gdb, clip_filename), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put all of the files in one geodatabase, could you just do this?

```
         for l_list in list:
               filename = code
               clip_filename = code
               # then change workspace to gdb
               arcpy.env.workspace = gdb location
               arcpy.clip code
               # then change workspace back to original workspace
               arcpy.env.workapace = original location
```